# Default methods and Lambda Supplier Callbacks

Tags: java, lambda

I welcome methods in the API to easily create default initialisations.
For example in HashMaps. But why have they not been provided with  Supplier Lambda methods? - Or am I missing an important step, or did I not learn the latest java Api versions?

Standard (Java8) version:

```
Map<String,List<Integer>> datas = new HashMap<>();
List<Integer> integersList = datas.getOrDefault( "somekey", new ArrayList<>() );
```

which would instantiate a new ArrayList anytime the code is executed - no matter if the new list is needed or not.

Desired Lambda supplier version:

```
Map<String,List<Integer>> datas = new HashMap<>();
List<Integer> integersList = datas.getOrDefault( "somekey", ()->new ArrayList() );
```

Would instantiate (or execute some instantiation code) only in case demanded key is not within the map.

The code of the *getOrDefault()*-Method could look something like this:

```
public V getOrDefault( K key, Supplier<V> supplier ) {
  if ( !super.containsKey( key ) && supplier != null ) {
    super.put( key, supplier.get() );
  }
  return super.get( key );
}
```

Why did they(?) not build it that way initially or added such functionality later on?

I guess there is even more examples where Lambda would solve an unnecessary code execution - not just Maps as shown with this example.

By the way: sorry for re-asking a question but I would not know how to exactly look for my question with different terms...
Be welcome to post helpful links.

Thanks for your shared knowledge :-)

Comment: Are you looking for computeIfAbsent?

Comment: `getOrDefault()` was never designed with collection/map values as main target. The common use case is that the default value is something immutable. You could have used `datas.getOrDefault( "somekey", Collections.emptyMap())`, or use `computeIfAbsent()` as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @Eran Yes. Thanks for asking and showing. Ok, it is all about learning API. Shame on me:-(
But I am confused because getOrDefault - sounds like it could do what I need plus It could be overloaded to do what I need. computeIfAbsent sounds like computing anything but not setting a value or changing a state. But thats my personal point of view. Like I said: it is all about learning APIs.
Jai, thanks for sharing as well.

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for exists since Java 8. Take a look at the javadoc of the HashMap and specifically the method [Hashmap.computeIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-). This method allows for adding new entries to the HashMap if none can be found using the key provided.

Examaple:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap();
String created = map.computeIfAbsent(1, k -> "Test");
System.out.println(created);
```

The code above will trigger the HashMap to call the provided Function to add a new entry since it cannot find an existing one. It both returns the new entry and call the Hashmap.put method to add it.

Comment: The side effects of the two methods are different. `getOrDefault` does not add an element to the map, whereas `computeIfAbsent` does. So it does not exactly cover the same need.

Comment: You are correct in that they should perform different things, but in regards to the original question and the code snippet they should use computeIfAbsent.